# join two lists of dictionaries on a single key

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Given `n` lists with `m` dictionaries as their elements, I would like to produce a new list, with a joined set of dictionaries. Each dictionary is guaranteed to have a key called "index", but could have an arbitrary set of keys beyond that. The non-index keys will never overlap across lists. For example, imagine the following two lists:

```
l1 = [{"index":1, "b":2}, {"index":2, "b":3}, {"index":3, "green":"eggs"}]
l2 = [{"index":1, "c":4}, {"index":2, "c":5}]
```

(`"b"` would never appear in `l2`, since it appeared in `l1`, and similarly, `"c"` would never appear in `l1`, since it appeared in `l2`)

I would like to produce a joined list:

```
l3 = [{"index":1, "b":2, "c":4}, 
      {"index":2, "b":3, "c":5}, 
      {"index":3, "green":"eggs"}]
```

What is the most efficient way to do this in Python?

Comment: Is it guaranteed that the value of the "index" entry in the dict will match the position of that dict in the list?

Comment: Nope - It is not guaranteed that "index" would match the position of the dict in the list.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

```
from collections import defaultdict

l1 = [{"index":1, "b":2}, {"index":2, "b":3}, {"index":3, "green":"eggs"}]
l2 = [{"index":1, "c":4}, {"index":2, "c":5}]

d = defaultdict(dict)
for l in (l1, l2):
    for elem in l:
        d[elem['index']].update(elem)
l3 = d.values()

# l3 is now:

[{'b': 2, 'c': 4, 'index': 1},
 {'b': 3, 'c': 5, 'index': 2},
 {'green': 'eggs', 'index': 3}]
```

**EDIT**: Since `l3` is not guaranteed to be sorted (`.values()` returns items in no specific order), you can do as @user560833 suggests:

```
from operator import itemgetter

...

l3 = sorted(d.values(), key=itemgetter("index"))
```

Comment: Was about to implement something very close to this.

Comment: You will need to sort l3 afterwards - it is not guaranteed that the list will be in order of the index. e.g. `from operator import itemgetter; l3.sort(key=itemgetter("index"))`

Comment: Instead off `for l in (l1, l2): for elem in l:` it is better to use directly `for elem in itertools.chain(l1, l2)`

Comment: This is quite efficient and readable, and as a bonus doesn't require any invocation of zip functions (which tend to get hairy quickly IME).  Compared to a dict comprehension with a `next` generator to fetch the corresponding key, this was several orders of magnitude faster.

Answer (score 19):

In python 3.5 or higher, you can [merge dictionaries in a single statement](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26853961/5858851).

So for python 3.5 or higher, a quick solution would be:

```
from itertools import zip_longest

l3 = [{**u, **v} for u, v in zip_longest(l1, l2, fillvalue={})]

print(l3)
#[
#    {'index': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 4}, 
#    {'index': 2, 'b': 3, 'c': 5}, 
#    {'index': 3, 'green': 'eggs'}
#]
```

However if the two lists were the same size, you could simply use zip:

```
l3 = [{**u, **v} for u, v in zip(l1, l2)]
```

---

Note: This assumes that the lists are sorted the same way by `index`, which is [stated by OP to not be the case in general](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5501810/join-two-lists-of-dictionaries-on-a-single-key#comment6244268_5501810).

In order to generalize for that case, one way is to create a custom zip-longest type function which yields values from the two lists only if they match on a key.

For instance:

```
def sortedZipLongest(l1, l2, key, fillvalue={}):  
    l1 = iter(sorted(l1, key=lambda x: x[key]))
    l2 = iter(sorted(l2, key=lambda x: x[key]))
    u = next(l1, None)
    v = next(l2, None)

    while (u is not None) or (v is not None):  
        if u is None:
            yield fillvalue, v
            v = next(l2, None)
        elif v is None:
            yield u, fillvalue
            u = next(l1, None)
        elif u.get(key) == v.get(key):
            yield u, v
            u = next(l1, None)
            v = next(l2, None)
        elif u.get(key) < v.get(key):
            yield u, fillvalue
            u = next(l1, None)
        else:
            yield fillvalue, v
            v = next(l2, None)
```

Now if you had the following out of order lists:

```
l1 = [{"index":1, "b":2}, {"index":2, "b":3}, {"index":3, "green":"eggs"}, 
      {"index":4, "b": 4}]
l2 = [{"index":1, "c":4}, {"index":2, "c":5}, {"index":0, "green": "ham"}, 
      {"index":4, "green": "ham"}]
```

Using the `sortedZipLongest` function instead of `itertools.zip_longest`:

```
l3 = [{**u, **v} for u, v in sortedZipLongest(l1, l2, key="index", fillvalue={})]
print(l3)
#[{'index': 0, 'green': 'ham'},
# {'index': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 4},
# {'index': 2, 'b': 3, 'c': 5},
# {'index': 3, 'green': 'eggs'},
# {'index': 4, 'b': 4, 'green': 'ham'}]
```

Whereas original method would produce the incorrect answer:

```
l3 = [{**u, **v} for u, v in zip_longest(l1, l2, fillvalue={})]
print(l3)
#[{'index': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 4},
# {'index': 2, 'b': 3, 'c': 5},
# {'index': 0, 'green': 'ham'},
# {'index': 4, 'b': 4, 'green': 'ham'}]
```

Comment: Excellent solution for `sortedZipLongest`. I think you can simplify it by replacing all the `None` values with `fillvalue` or simply `{}` since `fillvalue` has to be a dictionary to be unpacked later on using `**`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a one-liner that does this:

```
[dict(sum([z.items() for z in z2],[])) for z2 in [[x3 for x3 in l1+l2 if x3['index']==key] for key in set([x1['index'] for x1 in l1]+[x2['index'] for x2 in l2])]]
```

Not quite as elegant as a list-comprehension.  I don't think the result is guaranteed to necessarily be sorted the way you want either.

Expanding the one-liner:

```
[
    dict(sum([z.items() for z in z2],[])) 
    for z2 in [
        [
            x3 for x3 in l1+l2 if x3['index']==key
        ] for key in set(
            [x1['index'] for x1 in l1]+[x2['index'] for x2 in l2]
        )
    ]
]
```

The set expression on the 6th line gets all the unique index values from both lists.  The list comprehension around that (lines 3-9) creates a list of lists where each inner list is a combined list of dictionaries for that index/key with a particular index value.  The outermost list comprehension creates a single list of tuple-pairs for each key and converts it back to a list of dictionaries.

Comment: Using `sum` to flatten lists is inefficient- you should use `itertools.chain` instead: [why sum on lists is (sometimes) faster than itertools.chain?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41772165/5858851)