# Is there better way to merge dictionaries contained in two lists in Python?

Tags: python, list

I have two lists containing dictionaries:

**list_a:**

```
[{'id': 1, 'name': 'test'}, {'id': 2, 'name': 'test1'},....]
```

**list_b:**

```
[{'id': 1, 'age': 10}, {'id': 2, 'age': 20}, ....]
```

I want to merge these two lists with the result being:

```
[{'id': 1, 'name': 'test', 'age': 10}, {'id': 2, 'name': 'test1', 'age': 20}....]
```

I wan to use the nest loop to make it:

```
result= []
for i in list_a:
   for j in list_b:
     if i['id'] == j['id']:
      i['age']=j['age']
      result.append(i)
```

but there are 2000 elements for list_a, the ids of list_b is belongs to list_a, but the count of list_b is possibly less than 2000. the time complexityis of this method is too high, there a better way to merge them?

Comment: I guess you wanted `"name": "test1"` in your second merged dict?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a performance question, not a debugging question, meaning it belongs on Code Review, not Stack Overflow. http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [join two lists of dictionaries on a single key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5501810/join-two-lists-of-dictionaries-on-a-single-key)

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare Stack Overflow is for specific questions, not necessarily only for debugging. That said, I consider this question as "too broad" for Stack Overflow because there's too many possible answers, and am voting to close it as such.

Comment: Your intention is not clear to me, because you say nothing about handling common fields upon merge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really, but `dict.setdefault` and `dict.update` probably are your friends for this.

```
data = {}
lists = [
   [{'id': 1, 'name': 'test'}, {'id': 2, 'name': 'test1'},],
   [{'id': 1, 'age': 10}, {'id': 2, 'age': 20},]
]

for each_list in lists:
   for each_dict in each_list:
       data.setdefault(each_dict['id'], {}).update(each_dict)
```

Result:

```
>>> data
{1: {'age': 10, 'id': 1, 'name': 'test'},
 2: {'age': 20, 'id': 2, 'name': 'test1'}}
```

This way you can lookup by id (or just get `data.values()` if you want a plain list). Its been 20 years since I took my algorithms class, but I guess this is close enough to O(n) while your sample is more O(n²). This solution has some interesting properties: does not mutate the original lists, works for any number of lists, works for uneven lists containing distinct sets of "id".

Answer (score 0):

```
answer = {}
for d in list_a: answer[d['id']] = d

for d in list_b:
    if d['id'] not in d:
        answer[d['id']] = d
        continue
    for k,v in d.items():
        answer[d['id']][k] = v

answer = [d for k,d in sorted(answer.items(), key=lambda s:s[0])]
```

Answer (score 0):

No, I think this is the best way because you are joining all data in the simplest data structure.

You can know how to implement it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5501810/join-two-lists-of-dictionaries-on-a-single-key)

I hope my answer will be helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

It could be done in **one line**, given the items in list1 and list2 are in the same order, `id` wise, I mean.

```
result = [item1 for item1, item2 in zip(list1, list2) if not item1.update(item2)]
```

For a more lengthy one

```
for item1, item2 in zip(list1, list2):
    item1.update(item2)
    # list1 will be mutated to the result
```

Answer (score 0):

To find a better way one needs to know how the values are generated and how they will be used.

For example if you have them as `csv` files you can use a Table-like module like `pandas` (I'll create them from your lists but they have a `read_csv` and `from_csv` as well):

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict([{'id': 1, 'name': 'test'}, {'id': 2, 'name': 'test1'}])
df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict([{'id': 1, 'age': 10}, {'id': 2, 'age': 20}])
pd.merge(df1, df2, on='id')
```

[image]

Or if they come from a database most databases already have a `JOIN ON` (for example [MYSQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html)) option.