# Combine 2 dicts with a same key and value

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm working with `python` dictionaries and I want to combine it. The dicts are like below,

```
devices = [{'EUI':123,'Name':'gum 1'},{'EUI':456,'Name':'gum 2'},{'EUI':789,'Name':'gum 3'}]
data = [{'EUI':123,'data':111},{'EUI':456,'data':222},{'EUI':789,'data':333},{'EUI':456,'data':444},{'EUI':789,'data':555}]
```

They have in common the `EUI` (an identifier). What I'm doing is using a pair of loops and check if the `EUI` is the same or not. If is the same, I combine both dicts.

The final result is,

```
[{'EUI': 123, 'data': 111, 'Name': 'gum 1'}, {'EUI': 456, 'data': 222, 'Name': 'gum 2'}, {'EUI': 789, 'data': 333, 'Name': 'gum 3'}, {'EUI': 456, 'data': 444, 'Name': 'gum 2'}, {'EUI': 789, 'data': 555, 'Name': 'gum 3'}]
```

My full code is the following,

```
devices = [{'EUI':123,'Name':'gum 1'},{'EUI':456,'Name':'gum 2'},{'EUI':789,'Name':'gum 3'}]
data = [{'EUI':123,'data':111},{'EUI':456,'data':222},{'EUI':789,'data':333},{'EUI':456,'data':444},{'EUI':789,'data':555}]

print(data)

for da in data:
  for dev in devices:
    if dev['EUI'] == da['EUI']:
      da.update(dev)
      break

print(data)
```

Actually it works perfectly, but I think it could a better/easier/pythonic option to do the same. Somebody knows another way to do it?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Is always length of devices equal to len of data?

Comment: not necessary, I edited my post

Comment: In your revised data, there are data which have same `EUI` value with diffrent `data` value. What result is expected in that case? (For example, `(456, 222)` and `(456, 444)` for `('EUI', 'data')` pair.

Comment: The result what I have post, the EUI is the identifier of the sensor.

Comment: Actually what I'm doing is add the name of the sensor to the data dict.

Answer (score 1):

Since the `EUI` seems to be unique within the two lists of data you could use a dictionary right away, that maps EUI to other data:

```
devices = {d.pop('EUI'): d for d in devices}
data = {d.pop('EUI'): d for d in data}
```

And then you can merge on EUI keys:

```
for k, d in data.items():
    d.update(devices.get(k, {}))
```

Answer (score 0):

I considered case of `len(set(d['EUI'] for d in devices) ^ set(d['EUI'] for d in data)) > 0`.
This method preserves original `devices` and `data`.

```py
devices = [{'EUI': 123, 'Name': 'gum 1'}, {'EUI': 456, 'Name': 'gum 2'},
           {'EUI': 789, 'Name': 'gum 3'}]
data = [{'EUI': 123, 'data': 111}, {'EUI': 456, 'data': 222},
        {'EUI': 789, 'data': 333}]

device_dict = {
    device['EUI']: device
    for device in devices
}
results = [
    {**device_dict.pop(datum['EUI'], {}), **datum} for datum in data
] + list(device_dict.values())
print(results)
```

output:

```py
[{'EUI': 123, 'Name': 'gum 1', 'data': 111}, {'EUI': 456, 'Name': 'gum 2', 'data': 222}, {'EUI': 789, 'Name': 'gum 3', 'data': 333}]
```

explanation:

- `device_dict = {...}`: Making `EUI` keyed dictionary about `devices`.
- `[{**device_dict[datum['EUI']], **datum} for datum in data]`: Merging datum dictionary and device dictionary while looping data
- `**device_dict.pop(datum['EUI'], {})` instead of `**device_dict[datum['EUI']]`: Considering if `datum['EUI']` not in `device_dict`. Also `pop` from handled `EUI`s.
- `+ list(device_dict.values())`: Appending for rest of `device_dict`(dictionaries that are only in `devices`)

corner case data:

```py
devices = [{'EUI': 123, 'Name': 'gum 1'}, {'EUI': 456, 'Name': 'gum 2'},
           {'EUI': 789, 'Name': 'gum 3'}, {'EUI': 888, 'Name': 'gum 4'}]
data = [{'EUI': 123, 'data': 111}, {'EUI': 456, 'data': 222},
        {'EUI': 789, 'data': 333}, {'EUI': 777, 'data': 444}]
```

output:

```py
[{'EUI': 123, 'Name': 'gum 1', 'data': 111}, {'EUI': 456, 'Name': 'gum 2', 'data': 222}, {'EUI': 789, 'Name': 'gum 3', 'data': 333}, {'EUI': 777, 'data': 444}, {'EUI': 888, 'Name': 'gum 4'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

> from itertools import zip_longest
>
> result = [{**u, **v} for u, v in zip_longest(data, devices,
>   fillvalue={})] print(result)

Comment: this assumes the lists are ordered

Comment: similar question: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5501810/join-two-lists-of-dictionaries-on-a-single-key