# inside list of dictionaries, merge lists based on key

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have nested dictionaries in a list of dictionaries, I want to merge the lists based on `'id'`

```
res = [{'i': ['1'], 'id': '123'},
       {'i': ['1'], 'id': '123'},
       {'i': ['1','2','3','4','5','6'],'id': '123'},
       {'i': ['1'], 'id': '234'},
       {'i': ['1','2','3','4','5'],'id': '234'}]
```

Desired output:

```
[{'i': [1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 'id': '123'},
 {'i': [1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'id': '234'}]
```

I am trying to merge the nested dictionaries based on key `"id"`. I couldn't figure out the best way out:

```
import collections
d = collections.defaultdict(list)
for i in res:
    for k, v in i.items():
        d[k].extend(v)
```

The above code is merging all the lists, but i wantto merge lists based on key "id".

Comment: Have you checked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5501810/join-two-lists-of-dictionaries-on-a-single-key ?

Comment: Do you care about keys other than `i` and `id`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick

```python
from collections import defaultdict

merged = defaultdict(list)
for r in res:
    merged[r['id']].extend(r['i'])

output = [{'id': key, 'i': merged_list} for key, merged_list in merged.items()]
```

Answer (score 1):

The following produces the desired output, using `itertools.groupby`:

```
from operator import itemgetter
from itertools import groupby

k = itemgetter('id')

[
    {'id': k, 'i': [x for d in g for x in d['i']]} 
    for k, g in groupby(sorted(res, key=k), key=k)
]
```

Comment: Thanks @schwobaseggl for the snippet!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the expected behavior should be when there are duplicates -- for example, should the lists be:

- treated like a `set()` ?
- appended, and there could be multiple items, such as `[1,1,2,3...]` ?
- doesn't matter -- just take any

Here would be one variation where we use a [`dict comprehension`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries):

```
{item['id']: item for item in res}.values()
# [{'i': ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'], 'id': '234'}, {'i': ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6'], 'id': '123'}]
```

If you provide a bit more information in your question, I can update the answer accordingly.

Comment: @samuwelbrody1249 Thanks. I was looking to have duplicate elements in the list.