# How to combine two lists of dictionary based on a single key:value in python?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I wonder if there is a way to merge two list of dictionary base on a single key:value in each dictionary. As I tried to search and some cases, they seem did not match what I needed.

Suppose that I have two lists of dictionary as below:

```
[{'standoff_id': 1, 'entity_type': 'Concept', 'offset_start': 13, 'offset_end': 18, 'word': 'wheat'}, {'standoff_id': 2, 'entity_type': 'Concept', 'offset_start': 26, 'offset_end': 30, 'word': 'corn'}, {'standoff_id': 3, 'entity_type': 'Concept', 'offset_start': 61, 'offset_end': 67, 'word': 'barley'}]
[{'standoff_id': 1, 'concept_id': '8373'}, {'standoff_id': 2, 'concept_id': '12332'}, {'standoff_id': 3, 'concept_id': '823'}]
```

Those two lists always have the same length and I want to merge these two lists i.e each dictionary in parallel based on the **'standoff_id': id**.

My desired output is:

```
[{'standoff_id': 1, 'entity_type': 'Concept', 'offset_start': 13, 'offset_end': 18, 'word': 'wheat', 'concept_id': '8373'}, {'standoff_id': 2, 'entity_type': 'Concept', 'offset_start': 26, 'offset_end': 30, 'word': 'corn', 'concept_id': '12332'}, {'standoff_id': 3, 'entity_type': 'Concept', 'offset_start': 61, 'offset_end': 67, 'word': 'barley', 'concept_id': '823'}]
```

Any help would be much appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [join two lists of dictionaries on a single key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5501810/join-two-lists-of-dictionaries-on-a-single-key)

Answer (score 2):

Given that you say that your lists "always have the same length", and appear already to be sorted, I believe you can do this in one line. If you're using python >= 3.9, you can use the new `|` operator for dictionaries:

```
a = [{'standoff_id': 1, 'entity_type': 'Concept', 'offset_start': 13, 'offset_end': 18, 'word': 'wheat'}, {'standoff_id': 2, 'entity_type': 'Concept', 'offset_start': 26, 'offset_end': 30, 'word': 'corn'}, {'standoff_id': 3, 'entity_type': 'Concept', 'offset_start': 61, 'offset_end': 67, 'word': 'barley'}]
b = [{'standoff_id': 1, 'concept_id': '8373'}, {'standoff_id': 2, 'concept_id': '12332'}, {'standoff_id': 3, 'concept_id': '823'}]

merged_dicts = [(d1 | d2) for d1, d2 in zip(a, b)]
```

If you're using a version of python >=3.5 and <=3.8, you can achieve  the same result using dictionary unpacking;

```
merged_dicts = [{**d1, **d2} for d1, d2 in zip(a, b)]
```

If your dictionary lists are not always sorted, and/or they are not always the same length, you could do something like this:

```
from operator import itemgetter 
from itertools import groupby

standoff_id = itemgetter('standoff_id')
merged_dicts = []

for k, v in groupby(sorted((a + b), key=standoff_id), key=standoff_id):
    merged_dicts.append({key:val for d in v for key, val in d.items()})
```

Or, using `collections.ChainMap` instead of a dictionary comprehension (achieving the same outcome):

```
from operator import itemgetter 
from itertools import groupby
from collections import ChainMap

standoff_id = itemgetter('standoff_id')
merged_dicts = []

for k, v in groupby(sorted((a + b), key=standoff_id), key=standoff_id):
    merged_dicts.append(dict(ChainMap(*v)))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

- Sorting the lists based on the `standoff_id` to make the comparison easier.
- `d` will have the merged data.

```
a = [{'standoff_id': 1, 'entity_type': 'Concept', 'offset_start': 13, 'offset_end': 18, 'word': 'wheat'}, {'standoff_id': 2, 'entity_type': 'Concept', 'offset_start': 26, 'offset_end': 30, 'word': 'corn'}, {'standoff_id': 3, 'entity_type': 'Concept', 'offset_start': 61, 'offset_end': 67, 'word': 'barley'}]
b = [{'standoff_id': 1, 'concept_id': '8373'}, {'standoff_id': 2, 'concept_id': '12332'}, {'standoff_id': 3, 'concept_id': '823'}]

a.sort(key= lambda x: x['standoff_id'])
b.sort(key= lambda x: x['standoff_id'])

d = []

for i in range(len(a)):
    if a[i]['standoff_id'] == b[i]['standoff_id']:
        d.append(dict(a[i]))
        d[-1].update(b[i])

print(d)
```

```
[{'standoff_id': 1, 'entity_type': 'Concept', 'offset_start': 13, 'offset_end': 18, 'word': 'wheat', 'concept_id': '8373'}, {'standoff_id': 2, 'entity_type': 'Concept', 'offset_start': 26, 'offset_end': 30, 'word': 'corn', 'concept_id': '12332'}, {'standoff_id': 3, 'entity_type': 'Concept', 'offset_start': 61, 'offset_end': 67, 'word': 'barley', 'concept_id': '823'}]
```