# Array of dict to dict

Tags: python

I have arrays

```
first = [{'x': 'name1', 'a': '333'}, {'x': 'name2', 'a': '234'}, {'x': 'name3', 'a': '432'}, {'x': 'name4', 'a': '943'}, {'x': 'name5', 'a': '643'}]
second = [{'x': 'name1', 'b': '1333'}, {'x': 'name2', 'b': '1234'}, {'x': 'name3', 'b': '1432'}, {'x': 'name4', 'b': '1943'}]
```

What function can i use to get this result:

```
[{'x': 'name1', 'b': '1333', 'a': '333'}, {'x': 'name2', 'b': '1234', 'a': '234'}, {'x': 'name3', 'b': '1432', 'a': '432'}, {'x': 'name4', 'b': '1943', 'a': '943'}, {'x': 'name5', 'b': None, 'a': '643'}]
```

Comment: Are list items matched positionally, or on the value of the dictionary key `x`? Have you tried something yet yourself that we might use as a stepping stone?

Comment: @JonSG on the value of the dictionary key x

Comment: u re right, selected answer in not correct

Comment: Does this answer your question? [join two lists of dictionaries on a single key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5501810/join-two-lists-of-dictionaries-on-a-single-key)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply combine the dictionaries using `|` like so:

```
result = [f | s for f, s in zip(first, second)]
```

---

Based on your edited question, matching on `x`:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from functools import partial
from itertools import chain
# Each dict starts with defaults a, b == None
merged = defaultdict(partial(dict.fromkeys, ("a", "b")))

# Merge all dictionaries
for dict_ in chain(first, second):
    merged[dict_["x"]].update(dict_)

# Get the merged dicts
result = list(merged.values())
```

Comment: In Python 3.9.0 or greater (released 17 October 2020, PEP-584) you can do the union of dicts using: `z = x | y`

Comment: @Kins yup, that is correct :-)

Comment: thanks a lot! one more question, if in the first array i will have name5, but the second one doesn't contain that value, how can i add null there

Comment: @groutch according to updated question, fixed.

Comment: @JonSG according to specs.

Comment: @Bharel Looks good to me now :-)